# Single Trigger for multiple tables in Oracle SQL developer

Tags: triggers, oracle-sqldeveloper

I looked for this topic on almost every forum but found none convincing solution. I am using SQL Developer and here is where I am stuck.

I have 1000+ tables and I want to capture CRUD operations on each table in another AUDIT table.

For example Table A has columns `(a1,a2,a3)` and  Table B has columns `(b1,b2,b3)`. Now if a record is inserted and/or updated in Table A, a trigger will insert that record in AUDIT table with table name, column name and its value

```
(table ,col, value)
```

AUDIT TABLE will have this record - `( table A, a2, 'xyz')`. Same procedure for Table B.

I have an idea, of using meta table which will have list of all tables. Then a trigger on meta table, but this sounds little stupid and really complicated.

I am sorry, this is my first post so formatting is bad. Please help.

Comment: Have you looked at [Oracle's built-in auditing options](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/auditing-10gr2.php)?

Comment: I have. Oracle's Built in audit trails help in keep track of actions done by users of database. It doesn't help in capturing what values were updated/inserted/deleted.

Comment: FGA can capture values, but not really the way you want; you seem to want a history more than an audit. You can't have a table trigger that spans multiple tables, and the meta table idea wouldn't work unless each table was updating that, so they'd need their own triggers anyway, so you might as well just create the history directly from the table triggers. You could generate the trigger creation for each table programatically maybe, which would make the task a lot simpler?